# SQL group by clause error Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=,

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have query which calculate active clients by groups and must calculate pickups by groups.

```
SELECT  [Category] = ISNULL(c.Category, 'Total'),
        COUNT (hs.ClientID) as '3 Mo Clients',
        (COUNT (hs.ClientID))/3 as MoAVG
      ,(select COUNT(PickupID)from Pickup where PickupDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-03-30' group by CategCode) as '3 Mo Picups'

FROM    Category c 
        LEFT JOIN history hs
            ON hs.CategCode = c.CategCode 
            where ReccordDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-03-30'
GROUP BY Category
WITH ROLLUP
```

This query throws error :`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

if I am not using group by in 4 line it works but did not divide pickups by groups.
 This is example how does it works without group by clause in 4 line of the code
 
[image: Any Ideas how to fix it?]

Any Ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Silly comment: March has 31 days.

Comment: @ypercube doesn't mater right now it will take data from user. Yes `CategCode ` is in Pickup

Comment: why don't you join to pickup instead of using a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this condition: CategCode = c.CategCode

```
SELECT [Category] = ISNULL(c.Category, 'Total'),
       COUNT (hs.ClientID) as [3 Mo Clients],
       (COUNT (hs.ClientID))/3 as MoAVG
      ,(SELECT COUNT(PickupID) 
        FROM Pickup 
        WHERE PickupDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-03-30'
          AND  CategCode = c.CategCode
       ) AS [3 Mo Picups]
FROM Category c LEFT JOIN history hs ON hs.CategCode = c.CategCode 
WHERE ReccordDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-03-30'
GROUP BY c.CategCode, c.Category 
WITH ROLLUP
```

OR

```
SELECT [Category] = ISNULL(c.Category, 'Total'),
       COUNT (hs.ClientID) as [3 Mo Clients],
       (COUNT (hs.ClientID))/3 as MoAVG,
       SUM(o.cnt) AS [3 Mo Picups]
FROM Category c LEFT JOIN history hs ON hs.CategCode = c.CategCode
                CROSS APPLY (
                             SELECT COUNT(PickupID) AS cnt
                             FROM Pickup 
                             WHERE PickupDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-03-30'
                               AND  CategCode = c.CategCode
                             ) o
WHERE ReccordDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-03-30'
GROUP BY c.Category 
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: I tried this wariant also it was giving me this error `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'Category.CategCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: names of categories of clients first column on pic

Comment: if i use `WITH ROLLUP` it  put total under each column :( but it  works.

Comment: second example do not undetstand this line `o.cnt AS [3 Mo Picups]` but its ok i will use first and just  will calculate total and will not use `WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: Do you know way `WITH ROLLUP` add total line to each group not but not at the end on respond?